# How to run an emulated android device with a custom image?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I've created my own Android image and successfully ran it on a physical device. I've been searching on how to do the same with the AVD in android studio on windows but there's not much info on the topic. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The emulator is a different target, when you build (assuming you are using AOSP) you do

```
$ source build/envsetup.sh
```

then

```
$ lunch
```

and you select one of the emulator targets.

Comment: How did you create the image?

Comment: Followed the following guide http://jhshi.me/2014/11/09/aosp-release-tools/